# Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest

Tags: android, location

I am using gradle dependency of

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
```

at runtime I get below error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest;
```

I am trying to fetch lat long using LocationRequest and when I am using this code in a standalone project it works. And when I am trying to build a library with same code I get above error.

I have checked, both standalone project and library project have same dependencies and versions.

Comment: Is this error occurred in library compilation or app compilation when you include your library ?

Comment: This error occurs when I include my library in a third app. And its a runtime error in that third app.

Comment: is `minifyEnabled true` is enabled for your proguard ?

Comment: yes, minifyEnabled true in library code. should be done for app using the library ?

Comment: It would have cause the problem, but as you said you tried ignoring that class in Proguard file and didn't worked, so it doesn't matter

Answer (score 2):

This maybe because of **2 reasons**

**1st possible reason**

When you used this library directly you used `implementation` method in build.gradle.
So you can use it directly in ***simple app module***.

When you move it to ***your library*** and use that **location library** using same `implementation` option that **location library** can be only used by your library. and **can't** be used by **app module** in which you have used **your library**

Try by **replacing** that `implementation` by `api` for location library like this

```
api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
```

For more details refer this post for implementation vs api - [Here](https://medium.com/mindorks/implementation-vs-api-in-gradle-3-0-494c817a6fa)

---

**2nd possible reason**

As you mentioned in comments, its a runtime error

As per my opinion it maybe because of  **obfuscation by ProGuard**

add that class to keep ProGuard rule like this

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.location.** { *; }
```

So this will stop obfuscation of that Location Request class

Comment: I tried both the solutions , still getting same runtime error. In the second solution of adding location import in pro guard, I added the import one by one in library and app itself(which is using the library) ... still getting same result.

Comment: The app code is working now, with a very strange trail method. In the gradle of app(which uses my library) i put below dependency :      runtimeOnly 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'
and I get correct output without adding pro guard rules (I am using "api" in library instead of "implementation" as thats a better approach )

Comment: Which dependency you added to app(which uses your library) ?

Comment: any idea why it's working like this ?  The "runtimeOnly" documentation doesn't give any clear explanation for my case.

Comment: Its because app(which using your library) was not able to access location library from your library as it was using `implemented` method. Either you add same dependency to app or make it `api` in your library. Maybe runtimeCompile makes it availabe for runtime specially

Answer (score 0):

The code is working now with below changes (I am still looking for an explnation)

in the library gradle edited to below dependency

```
compileOnly "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1"
```

and in the app's gradle file added below dependency

```
runtimeOnly 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'
```

- my guess is, since "compileOnly" takes care of adding the dependency in library and "runtimeOnly" takes care of using that dependency the code works and is able to find LocationRequest class.

P.S adityakamble49 's answer in the thread also helped. Please try that as well as it might work for your case.